# Remove VrPanoramaView cardboard tag in android

Tags: android, google-vr, 360-panorama

To show panorma view in android i got one gradle dependency like 'com.google.vr:sdk-panowidget:1.120.0' it works fine for every image. But some extra icons are there on this View like  to see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU60e.jpg)Full-View, cardboard icons etc How can we remove all these icons.

Answer (score 1):

On your view you can call the following to disable the buttons that are part of the view, such as:

```
private VrPanoramaView vrView;

...

vrView.setInfoButtonEnabled(false);
vrView.setFullscreenButtonEnabled(false);
vrView.setStereoModeButtonEnabled(false);
```

Hope this helps.